# How to get the value from a nested array with objects

Tags: javascript

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3aq286rx/4/

I have an array which has nested arrays and objects

I wanted to label the colors like `#f00` is `red` etc. etc.

I have a random number generator function which generates a random number from 0 to 2: `getRandNUM(1)`

Let's say the number is 2 I want to be able to pull `#0f0` from my arrays without having to use `.green` because I wouldnt know the label based on the random number.

How can I do that

script:

```
var defaults = {
 backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 weekdays: ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'],
 colors: [
    {
    red: [
      "#f00"
      ]
  },
  {
    blue: [
      "#00f"
      ]
  },
  {
    green: [
      "#0f0"
      ]
  }
 ]
};

alert(defaults.colors[0].red);
```

Comment: Can you change the structure of `defaults`? It could be much better organized

Comment: Yes.... please let me know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `colors` being an array of objects, where the only key is the name of the color and the value is an array with a single string of the hex code, make `colors` an array of objects, each with a `color`, and `name`.  You can then generate your random number and use it to pick out the object in colors.  Then you can use `.color` or `.name` to get the value you desire.

```js
var defaults = {
  backgroundcolor: '#000',
  color: '#fff',
  weekdays: ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
  colors: [{
      color: "#f00",
      name: "red"
    },
    {
      color: "#00f",
      name: "blue"
    },
    {
      color: "#0f0",
      name: "green"
    }
  ]
};

// however you generate your random number
var randomNumber = 2;

alert(defaults.colors[randomNumber].color);
```

Comment: This could work for me as I am looking to add more complex objects so changing the format is best... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Structure your object as follows (https://jsfiddle.net/3aq286rx/14/):

```
var defaults = {
 backgroundcolor: '#000',
 color: '#fff',
 weekdays: ['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'],
 colors: 
    {
    red: "#f00",      
    blue: "#00f",
    green: "#0f0"
    }
};
```

then use Object.keys:

```
alert(defaults.colors.red);
alert(defaults.colors[Object.keys(defaults.colors)[0]]);
```

where [0] is your random number